# How can i check the value of JFormattedTextField is what i need?

Tags: java, swing

```
MaskFormatter mf = new MaskFormatter("(0###) ### - ## - ##"); // format
JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField(mf);
```

With this code i get a phone number from user. For example "(0444) 111 - 12 - 34".

If user write nothing i get a string like this "(0   )     -    -   ".How can i check it if it is empty or not. And did the user write all numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String text = formattedTextField.getText().toString();
Boolean flag1 = Character.isDigit(text.charAt(2));

if(flag1){
   System.out.println("NUMBER");
}else{
   System.out.println("NOT NUMBER");
}
```

I can check with this code.